# Unity. How to use Color.RGBToHSV() in Unity c#

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Learning English] I did not find Unity examples of using RGBToHSV(). I'm trying different code combinations but I do not know how to use properly RGBToHSV(). I try to use just the function but do not work. In Unity documentation and forum there is no example. Do I need to add Color to the function first? also I try *myColor = to Color.RGBToHSV(...)* but is not working. How is the correct way to use RGBToHSV() function?

```
// Declaration
public float hue { get; set; }
float S, V;

Color.RGBToHSV (actualRGBColor, out hue, out S, out V);
```

But err: A property or indexer GetSetColor.hue may not be passed as `ref' or`out' parameter.

**How to use properly Color.RGBToHSV() in Unity c# ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use GetSetColor.hue as the out variable.

You will have to pass in a variable instead.

```
float hue, S, V;
Color.RGBToHSV (actualColor, out hue, out S, out V);
```

Comment: `int hue, S, V;` should be `float hue, S, V;`

Comment: Yes that Get Set was the problem so I will include it in the question.